# Why is llvm::Module stored in a unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, llvm, unique-ptr

In the [LLVM Kaleidoscope](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl03.html#code-generation-setup) tutorial, I found the following code:

```
static std::unique_ptr<Module> TheModule;
```

I'm confused as to why this was stored in a unique_ptr rather than a regular global variable. Maybe the object is too big that it would be more efficient to do a heap allocation instead of stack? After all, `sizeof(Module)` is 728 on my system. Can I get a concrete answer for this that isn't based on speculation? Thanks.

Comment: Context is important to explain such choices. It will help if you link to the place in the tutorial where you've seen this. Especially if you want an answer "that isn't based on speculation".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [chapter 4](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl04.html#adding-a-jit-compiler) `TheModule` is cheaply moved into the JIT (AFAIK then deleted after code generation) and then reinitialized with a new `Module`, this would not work with a static `Module` variable.

```
  auto H = TheJIT->addModule(std::move(TheModule));
  InitializeModuleAndPassManager(); // here a new empty module is created
```

While it would be possible to write the JIT to pass a plain `Module` pointer to `IRCompileLayer`, a static `Module` variable could not be replaced by a new module afterwards.

The tutorial says this:

> Once the module has been added to the JIT it can no longer be
>   modified, so we also open a new module to hold subsequent code by
>   calling InitializeModuleAndPassManager().

```
static void InitializeModuleAndPassManager() {
  // Open a new module.
  TheModule = llvm::make_unique<Module>("my cool jit", TheContext);
```

If TheModule was a `Module` and not a `unique_ptr<Module>` this assignment would fail.

Comment: Looking into the documentation, the only real usage of the given Module is from [IRCompileLayer](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1orc_1_1IRCompileLayer.html) which takes a shared_ptr, only to pass it dereferenced to [SimpleCompiler](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1orc_1_1SimpleCompiler.html) which takes a reference.

Comment: @Taylor Hansen: I updated the answer to more clearly state that the assignment to the module will fail.